# Web servers configured to use 'localhost' not accessible inside network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-14.04

What would cause an Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS machine to lose the ability to use 'localhost' in web-server configurations?  If I replace 'localhost' with the machine's static, internal IP address (192.168.0.70), then other machines on the network can access the site.  If I try using 'localhost', the same request is unreachable (let's say I'm using http://192.168.0.70:8000 for both scenarios).  I've duplicated this with 2 different web server technologies, so it isn't a web-server problem.  The '/etc/hosts' file has an entry for '127.0.0.1 localhost', and I can ping 'localhost' on the machine in question.  I have the ufw firewall running and allowing tcp traffic on port 8000.  Since I can access the site from other machines when using the IP configuration, then I know it isn't a firewall issue.

Comment: `localhost` is the loopback. It is exactly as it sounds: `this local host`. You can't access a remote computer using loopback. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: You **cannot** access a remote machine by using `http://localhost` or the like.

Comment: I've figured out my issue (joeqwerty is right of course).  I've been using nginx too long.  Setting server_name to localhost works in this scenario.  One can access the site in the local network by just using the server's IP address.  Doing the same thing with node.js does not work.  In the case of node.js, I had to change 'localhost' to '192.168.0.70' to get things working.  Nginx must be doing some magic to translate the request.

Comment: "You can't access a remote computer using loopback." actually you can, if you will edit /etc/hosts file, but this is bad idea in common

Answer (score 0):

localhost is loopback only. It is internal in the machine, private, and not related to localhost on any other machine. If you want to serve on the wired interface, it has to listen on that interface. So you either listen to that one, or * (all), or a list that includes localhost if you need it, plus the wired interface. (in config, sometimes you put an ip, and sometimes you put an interface)

You can see it in lsof also. Here is a web server which listens to all:

```
root@webthingy # lsof -Pni | grep "TCP.*:80.*LISTEN"

apache2   26080     root    3u  IPv4 450401823      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   26485 www-data    3u  IPv4 450401823      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Here is a dns server that listens to a list rather than all (UDP doesn't show up as LISTEN but that's what these are):

```
root@dnsthingy:~ # lsof -Pni | grep named.*:53
named   13132  bind   20u  IPv4 13389831      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
named   13132  bind   21u  IPv4 13389833      0t0  TCP 10.2.0.2:53 (LISTEN)
named   13132  bind  512u  IPv4 13389830      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53 
named   13132  bind  513u  IPv4 13389832      0t0  UDP 10.2.0.2:53
```